# UnboundLocalError when calling nested function defined after the call

Tags: python, coding-style

Say i have a very long function, often i want to break it down to smaller ones to improve readability.

```
class A:
    def long_function(self):
        self.helper1()
        self.helper2()
        ...
        return

    def helper1(self):
        #hardwork
    ...
```

I then discovered that python functions can be declared inside other functions, this helps organizing code since it limits the scope of the helper functions, and also takes out the `self` if not needed. So:

```
class A:
    def long_function(self):
        helper1()
        helper2()
        ...
        return

        def helper1():
            #hardwork
        def helper2():
            #more hardwork
```

BUT, python sends me an `UnboundLocalError` saying that `'helper1'` is referenced before assignment. I know that I could define them on top of their calls, but that would defeat all purpose of easy readability. I could also continue filling my classes with private methods but I consider that sub-optimal.

Do you have any sugestions?

Comment: Why would defining the helper functions at the start reduce readability?

Comment: How do you read your newspaper? You see the headlines, then the subheadlines, then the front cover text and then finally (if you want) you can go to the page and read the whole thing. What i mean is, detail should be at the bottom, when i read a function i want the first line to get to the point, and not to be a declaration of a helper that maybe i dont even want to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions are executed top to bottom.  `def` is an executable statement like any other, and is executed when execution reaches it.  If you write the `def helper1` at the end of the function, `helper1` will not be defined until the end of the function.  You can't use it at the beginning if it's not defined until the end.

If you want to break your method into smaller ones, do it the way you did it in your first example.  There's nothing suboptimal about that.  You can name these helper methods with one leading underscore (.e.g, `_helper1`) to alert users that they are not part of the public API.

Comment: I think its sub-optimal beacause it does not limit the scope of helper1, and it gives a feeling that this method depends on the class object (from the self argument) even when it doesn't even use self.

Comment: @polvoazul: If the function doesn't depend on the instance, move it out of the class and just make it a function.  (Or make it a staticmethod.)